# Человек-на-Луне — использование дефисов

Tags: орфография, ономастика, дефис

> Однажды **Человек-на-Луне** посмотрел вниз на Землю и увидел большущего пса, который с громким лаем гнался за маленькой кошкой.
>   Дональд Биссет. Сказка «Мистер Крококот»

Нормально использовать дефисы в таком имени?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нормально.
Именно дефис собирает обычные слова (не имена собственные) в одно слово (имя).

Иначе получалось бы не имя, а просто фраза:
*(Кто?) Человек (где?) на Луне.*

С дефисами:
*(Кто?) Человек-на-Луне.* || Вопрос *где?* уже не получается задать.

Comment: Красная шапочка?

Comment: В оригинале "Red Riding Hood" нет дефиса. Думаю, что здесь дело именно в предлогах (**на** Луне, **с** пальчик). Именно тогда имя пишут через дефисы. Туда же "рок-н-ролл".

Comment: В оригинале и у мальчика нет. Подозреваю, что и у Биссета дефисов нет, не могу текст найти.

Comment: Есть Man-in-the-moon

Comment: Просто в оригинале мальчика "Le Petit Poucet" нет предлога. Есть английский вариант с дефисами - "Hop-o-My-Thumb".

Answer (score 0):

Нормально. Мальчик-с-пальчик вас не смущает?

Comment: Смущает. Это же не двойная фамилия.

Comment: Вы тогда сформулируйте сферу того, что именно вас смущает. Возможно, ваш вопрос и не лишен смысла.